# Is there any evidence that Jesus' Mother lived in Ephesus?

Tags: christianity, religious-history, asia-minor

There is a Shrine Chapel in the ancient city of Ephesus-(present-day Efes, Turkey) that is dedicated to Jesus' Mother, Mary, titled, "[House of the Virgin Mary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_the_Virgin_Mary)" which is administered by The Roman Catholic Church; (It is also referred to as, "Our Lady of Ephesus").  It is a simple and rather humble looking stone house located in the distant corner of ancient Ephesus. The lore behind the House is that Jesus' Mother lived there shortly after his death.  She is also believed to have died in this House, thereby making it both a historical and a sacred site for practicing Christians-(in particular, Roman Catholics).

However, is there any incontrovertible historical proof that Mary traveled to Ephesus after Jesus' death and lived in this particular Ephesian House? Are there any written records? Is there any available archaeological evidence validating this claim? Or is this particular House part of the larger Christian lore?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the Christianity site.

Comment: This is a legitimate history question. As I stated earlier, my question has no mentioning of Mary's religious character; instead, it is asking about Mary's historical whereabouts.

Comment: It is a historical question obviously.

Comment: To date, no contemporary historical or archaeological evidence has been found to confirm the existence of an historical Jesus. Given that, why would you expect there to be historical or archaeological evidence for his mother? If your interest lies in the Christian lore, then @PieterGeerkens is correct, this question belongs on the Christianity site.

Comment: Alex, the records might be [Apocrypha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocrypha). If you are sincere in wanting to know the particulars of why that house is believed as such, Christianity is the right SE sight. If you are interested in solid evidence for that sight, (i.e., you want to argue that it isn't correct, or you have an anti-religious axe to grind) then go to SE Skeptics.

Comment: Okay, a few points to clarify.  This posting has to do with the historical whereabouts of Jesus' Mother after his death.......that's it.  With regard to the historical existence of Jesus, that is an entirely different discussion.  I am not an expert in Biblical History or in the biography of Jesus. However, if you legitimize the synoptic Gospels, as well as the defunct Gospel writings-(dating to the age of the Council of Nicea), as well as the historical writings of Tacitus and Flavius Josephus, there is enough textual evidence pointing to a historical Jesus.

Comment: The diverse writings regarding Jesus' life range from the Gospels, which portray him as a miraculous, prophetic and seemingly deified figure whereas Flavius Josephus' describes Jesus as a Magician-(though a very popular Magician).  Yet, Josephus does not depict Jesus as a deified, prophetic or messianic figure, instead, Josephus portrays Jesus as a very human and historical figure with crowds of followers.  In other words, Josephus, albeit in a shorter account, provides his audience with a historical-(and not a supernatural) description and depiction of Jesus.

Comment: Now, I am not saying, Josephus's writings singularly prove that Jesus was a historical figure; what I am suggesting is that Josephus, was a self-identified Historian and not a Mythologist. Josephus, unlike the Gospel Writers, was not promoting a supernatural agenda. Instead,Josephus was writing about the history of a certain time whereby a popular figure named Jesus had lived.....that's it.

Comment: If you are of the school of thought that does not trust written sources for historical evidence and if you are of the school of thought that requires the presence of an actual body, then everything that I just posted will be meaningless to you.  However, if you of are the school of thought that legitimizes and gives credibility to written sources as accurate or fairly accurate descriptions of an age, as well as portraits of a person's biography, then perhaps the above postings may change your position regarding this topic.

Comment: It seems to me that OP has carefully constructed this question to ask for historical evidence.  I suspect that the answer is "No, there is no evidence", but I'm not an expert in the field.

Comment: @sempaiscuba do you know what the dead sea scrolls are / where?

Comment: Paul's letter to the Ephesians: the inventor of Christianity, who never met Christ, writes his theories that didn't get traction in Judea, to this place where 'the mother' lived and told her side of the story? As credible as Jesus' tomb in Kashmir? And Josephus' testimonium?

Comment: @NeilMeyer Yes / they are stored in the [Shrine of the Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrine_of_the_Book) in Israel. I have a translation on my bookshelf.  I also know they do not mention Jesus or his family. Why do you ask?

Comment: I must admit that I never heard of Jesus' tomb in Kashmir. I have heard of the possibility of Jesus having traveled to India, though such a story, seems unlikely and there is no evidence of Jesus traveling beyond the Middle East.

Comment: With regard to Paul, I wouldn't exactly describe his writings as, "theories".  They were "Letters" and "Acts"-(co-authored by Luke) and according to Paul, there was nothing theoretical or mythical about the historical Jesus. Is Paul the Inventor of Christianity?.....No, the Inventor of Christianity.......was Jesus of Nazareth.

Comment: Paul, was Christianity's earliest international Missionary-(with the possible exception of James/"Santiago").

Comment: A theory about the origin of special worship of Mary in Ephesos: Ephesos had a large cult of Artemis, the Greek goddess of hunter and also a virgin. So maybe the cult of one virgin was converted into a cult for the other one.

Answer (score -5):

Shall we look first if Mary really existed? Wikipedia doesn't go into any historical detail at all here. None whatsoever.

Now, if she existed she possibly/probably was 12-13 when she became mother. In those days that was quite normal for girls. But she was not married. According to the lore, she was engaged to Joseph. Being pregnant before marriage, most certainly when the father is not the husband-to-be was not a good idea. Generally speaking, if she wasn't dragged to the edge of town to be stoned, she would be very lucky indeed. The source about Mamzer is a bit vague about it, but if she remained alive she almost certainly would be considered a social outcast.

But Joseph was a loving man, etc. apologists will claim. Joseph was a man of his time. He had his reputation to worry about. Marrying a pregnant fiancée by someone else would make him the laughing stock not of the village, but of the district. He would be known as Joseph with the horns for the rest of his life. He must have been **deeply** in love to carry that stygma.

Being a bastard became only socially acceptable after WW2. Before WW2 it was a shame you did well to hide. Especially for the mother. *(I'm not disrespectful to your religion, but that is the technical term for someone born out of wedlock.)*

I conclude that Mary probably didn't exist, just as Jesus (being the son of a god) never existed. I'm not a theologian, but assume existing mother goddesses form the basis of Mary, the mother of Jesus. There are plenty of immaculate birth legends.

Based on the above, no doubt there is a church dedicated the virgin Mary in Ephesus. But that doesn't proof anything. Not even that Mary lived there. Only that people worshiped her.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary,_mother_of_Jesus
- https://www.quora.com/How-old-was-Mary-mother-of-Jesus-when-she-gave-birth-to-Jesus
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamzer
- http://www.stephanielandsem.com/2013/12/unwed-and-pregnant/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckold
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miraculous_births

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70533/discussion-on-answer-by-jos-is-there-any-evidence-that-jesus-mother-lived-in-ep).